# Recursive Descent Parser in Erlang

Tags: parsing, recursion, erlang

I'm trying to construct a RDP in Erlang. So far I have read and processed a file of tokens, which I will pass to the function as eg [2,6,3,7,3,2,4,6,3,2,4,4,99] (sample input that should work) and I need to ensure that every character(or set of) can be derived to by transforming from the default rule [bexp0] into some matching list of terminals.

```
get_terminal_list() ->
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,99].

get_prod_list() ->
[bexp0,bexp,bexp1,bterm].

get_sym_list(Prod) ->
    case Prod of
        bexp0 -> [[bexp,99]];
        bexp  -> [[bterm,bexp1]];
        bexp1 -> [[5,bexp,bexp1],[6,bexp,bexp1]];
        bterm -> [[3,bexp,4],[2],[8],[9],[2,10,1],[2,12,1],[2,11,1],[7,bterm]]
    end.
```

get_sym_list shows the grammar in use - where each int stands for a terminal character and each sublist is a set, i.e. bterm-> [[7,bterm]] means that bterm can turn into terminal '7' followed by non-terminal 'bterm'.

Right now I'm working on somehow realizing this:

```
Check if first set of rule has some terminal
 if so, check which side, reduce list of tokens from same side until first occurrence of this token,  
     parse this new list (w/o token) with rest of the set of this rule (also without the matched terminal). 
       return {success|failure, list_of_tokens, list_of_rules}  
   if success -> check with new list_of_tokens, default_rule
   if failure, check with old list_of_tokens, and new list_of_rules.
```

I assume the end states will be reached if the list of rules is empty - hence we have exhausted every possible production, hence not valid, or
list of tokens is empty, hence we have matched every token/set of tokens to some rule

Comment: Upvote because it's in erlang.

Comment: Can you add an example of an input you are trying to parse? And what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error or the algorithm doesn't seem to produce what you expect (in which case please state what you expect), or something else?

Comment: @Amiramix added sample input to question. Currently I think it gets in a loop, or an error once it reaches a production that is a list.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like your function takes two lists as initial arguments, not one: List and NT. And you provided one list as the sample input.

Comment: @Amiramix yep, the 2nd list is a list of a single atom that i directly send to the function when i initially call it, [bexp]

Comment: It would help if you tried to parse the input manually, because I don't see any production matching `2,6` that's in the beginning of the input list. For that to work `2` would need to match `[5,bterm,bexp2]` somehow but that will always start with `5`. Can you provide a sequence of reduction that in your opinion should match the input list before even writing a parser for it? BTW I think there is a mistake, this line should probably look like this: `parse(List, get_sym_list(Q) ++ Rest_of_NT)` - without the list.

Comment: @Amiramix I did some work turning the grammar into CNF and removing left recursion which I will update now, hopefully that makes things easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this will do what you want:

```
-module(parse).
-export([parse1/0, parse1/1, parse2/0, parse2/1]).

parse1() ->
    parse([bexp], [2,6,3,7,3,2,4,6,3,2,4,4,99], fun get_sym_list1/1).

parse1(Input) ->
    parse([bexp], Input, fun get_sym_list1/1).


parse2() ->
    parse([bexp0], [2,6,3,7,3,2,4,6,3,2,4,4,99], fun get_sym_list2/1).

parse2(Input) ->
    parse([bexp0], Input, fun get_sym_list2/1).


parse([], [], _) ->
    true;
parse([], _, _) ->
    false;
parse([X | TX], [X | TY], Fun) ->
    io:format("+ Current:~w\tTokens:~w Input:~w~n", [X, TX, TY]),
    parse(TX, TY, Fun);
parse([X | TX], Input, Fun) ->
    io:format("  Current:~w\tTokens:~w Input:~w~n", [X, TX, Input]),
    case lists:member(X, get_terminal_list()) of
        true -> false;
        false -> lists:any(fun(T) -> parse(T ++ TX, Input, Fun) end, Fun(X))
    end.

get_terminal_list() ->
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,99].

get_sym_list1(Prod) ->
    case Prod of
        bexp    -> [[bexp1],[bterm],[bterm,bexp2]];
        bexp1   -> [[99]];
        bexp2   -> [[5,bterm,bexp2],[6,bterm,bexp2]];
        bterm   -> [[bfactor],[7,bterm]];
        bfactor -> [[3,bexp,4],[bconst],[2,10,1],[2,12,1],[2,11,1],[2]];
        bconst  -> [[8],[9]]
    end.

get_sym_list2(Prod) ->
    case Prod of
        bexp0 -> [[bterm,bexp1]];
        bexp  -> [[bterm,bexp1]];
        bexp1 -> [[5,u1],[6,bexp,bexp1],[99]];
        bterm -> [[u1,4],[2],[8],[9],[2,10,1],[2,12,1],[2,11,1],[7,bterm]];
        u1    -> [[3,bexp]]
    end.
```

However, it looks like either the grammar or the input list is incorrect because as far as I can see neither the old nor the new grammar parses the input. And it seems to be working fine because it will parse an input like this one:

```
41> parse:parse2([2,6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]).
  Current:bexp0 Tokens:[] Input:[2,6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:bterm Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[2,6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:u1    Tokens:[4,bexp1] Input:[2,6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:3     Tokens:[bexp,4,bexp1] Input:[2,6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
+ Current:2     Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:bexp1 Tokens:[] Input:[6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:5     Tokens:[u1] Input:[6,8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
+ Current:6     Tokens:[bexp,bexp1] Input:[8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:bexp  Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:bterm Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:u1    Tokens:[4,bexp1,bexp1] Input:[8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:3     Tokens:[bexp,4,bexp1,bexp1] Input:[8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:2     Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[8,5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
+ Current:8     Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:bexp1 Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[5,3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
+ Current:5     Tokens:[u1,bexp1] Input:[3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:u1    Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[3,bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
+ Current:3     Tokens:[bexp,bexp1] Input:[bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:bexp  Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[bterm,5,3,9,99,99]
+ Current:bterm Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[5,3,9,99,99]
  Current:bexp1 Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[5,3,9,99,99]
+ Current:5     Tokens:[u1,bexp1] Input:[3,9,99,99]
  Current:u1    Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[3,9,99,99]
+ Current:3     Tokens:[bexp,bexp1] Input:[9,99,99]
  Current:bexp  Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[9,99,99]
  Current:bterm Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[9,99,99]
  Current:u1    Tokens:[4,bexp1,bexp1] Input:[9,99,99]
  Current:3     Tokens:[bexp,4,bexp1,bexp1] Input:[9,99,99]
  Current:2     Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[9,99,99]
  Current:8     Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[9,99,99]
+ Current:9     Tokens:[bexp1,bexp1] Input:[99,99]
  Current:bexp1 Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[99,99]
  Current:5     Tokens:[u1,bexp1] Input:[99,99]
  Current:6     Tokens:[bexp,bexp1,bexp1] Input:[99,99]
+ Current:99    Tokens:[bexp1] Input:[99]
  Current:bexp1 Tokens:[] Input:[99]
  Current:5     Tokens:[u1] Input:[99]
  Current:6     Tokens:[bexp,bexp1] Input:[99]
+ Current:99    Tokens:[] Input:[]
true
```

BTW `true` means the input has been parsed and `false` that it has not.

Comment: That is beautiful man, a parser in some 7 lines. I'm reworking the grammar again, maybe I can get it right for once, but the sample input is a correct one.

Comment: Yeah, the code can be really concise in Erlang, which is what I like. I am glad it finally worked. BTW It may be not relevant to your project at hand but in general Erlang supports proper parsers and tokenizers with yecc and leex, so you might look into that at some point. Here is a good description how to use it, from Elixir's perspective, but nevertheless well worth a read: http://andrealeopardi.com/posts/tokenizing-and-parsing-in-elixir-using-leex-and-yecc/

Comment: maybe what's happening that's causing errors is that 6 has to be preceeded by a bterm, so if the case fails maybe we have to try to check the pair together? i hvae updated the rules too, but nothing particular changed other than making sure that 99 has to be at the end of an input stream

Comment: I would propose that you start with the root symbol and go down replacing tokens with production and ensuring that at each stop the input parses properly. It's quite difficult to debug the parsed grammar going from the bottom up if the grammar is parsed from the top down.